# How to combine two data sets in excel graphs by adding a continuous x axis

Tags: excel, axis, continuous

first data set

[image]

Second data set

[image]

How to combine these two in excel and draw a graph with the same x axis?

Comment: Combine the data using one variable then plot that.

Comment: 1. need to make the 1st column in 1st dataset in the same unit as 2nd data set. (your data in 1st dataset seems to be a string, not a time value. If it is a range, you can take the average as a point.Expand the table for multiple range) 2. then select that data, press F11, select XY scatter. 3. when u had done plotting/configuring, you may add data point via the options on the menu.